# Python 3.8 shared_memory resource_tracker producing unexpected warnings at application close

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-3.8

- I am using a `multiprocessing.Pool` which calls a function in 1 or more subprocesses to produce a large chunk of data.
- The worker process creates a `multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory` object and uses the default name assigned by `shared_memory`.
- The worker returns the string name of the `SharedMemory` object to the main process.
- In the main process the `SharedMemory` object is linked to, consumed, and then **unlinked & closed**.

At shutdown I'm seeing warnings from `resource_tracker`:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 10 leaked shared_memory objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:229: UserWarning: resource_tracker: '/psm_e27e5f9e': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/psm_e27e5f9e'
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: %r: %s' % (name, e))
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:229: UserWarning: resource_tracker: '/psm_2cf099ac': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/psm_2cf099ac'
<8 more similar messages omitted>
```

Since I unlinked the shared memory objects in my main process I'm confused about what's happening here. I suspect these messages are occurring in the subprocess (in this example I tested with a process pool of size 1).

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.shared_memory as shared_memory

def create_shm():
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=30000000)
    shm.close()
    return shm.name

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    tasks = [pool.apply_async(create_shm) for _ in range(200)]

    for task in tasks:
        name = task.get()
        print('Getting {}'.format(name))
        shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=name, create=False)
        shm.close()
        shm.unlink()

    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have found that running that example on my own laptop (Linux Mint 19.3) it runs fine, however running it on two different server machines (unknown OS configurations, but both different) it does exhibit the problem. In all cases I'm running the code from a docker container, so Python/software config is identical, the only difference is the Linux kernel/host OS.

I notice this documentation that might be relevant: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods

I also notice that the number of "leaked shared_memory objects" varies from run to run. Since I unlink in main process, then immediately exit, perhaps this `resource_tracker` (which I think is a separate process) has just not received an update before the main process exits. I don't understand the role of the `resource_tracker` well enough to fully understand what I just proposed though.

Related topics:

- https://bugs.python.org/issue39959

Comment: Well written question - thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In theory and based on the current implementation of `SharedMemory`, the warnings should be expected. The main reason is that every shared memory object you have created is being tracked twice: first, when it's produced by one of the processes in the `Pool` object; and second, when it's consumed by the main process. This is mainly because the current implementation of the constructor of `SharedMemory` will `register` the shared memory object regardless of whether the `create`argument is set to `True` or its value is `False`.

So, when you call `shm.unlink()` in the main process, what you are doing is deleting the shared memory object entirely before its producer (some process in the `Pool`) gets around to cleaning it up. As a result, when the pool gets destroyed, each of its members (if they ever got a task) has to clean up after itself. The first warning about leaked resources *probably* refers to the shared memory objects actually created by processes in the `Pool` that never got `unlinked` ***by those same processes***. And, the `No such file or directory` warnings are due to the fact that the main process has `unlinked` the files associated with the shared memory objects before the processes in the `Pool` are destroyed.

The solution provided in [the linked bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue39959) would likely prevent consuming processes from having to spawn additional resource trackers, but it does not quite prevent the issue that arises when a consuming process decides to delete a shared memory object that it did not create. This is because the process that produced the shared memory object will still have to do some clean up, i.e. some `unlinking`, before it exits or is destroyed.

The fact that you are not seeing those warnings is quite puzzling. But it may well have to do with a combination of OS scheduling, unflushed buffers in the child process and the start method used when creating a process pool.

For comparison, when I use `fork` as a start method on my machine, I get the warnings. Otherwise, I see no warnings when `spawn` and `forkserver` are used. I added argument parsing to your code to make it easy to test different start methods:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# shm_test_script.py
"""
Use --start_method or -s to pick a process start method when creating a process Pool.
Use --tasks or -t to control how many shared memory objects should be created.
Use --pool_size or -p to control the number of child processes in the create pool.
"""
import argparse
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.shared_memory as shared_memory


def create_shm():
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=30000000)
    shm.close()
    return shm.name


def main(tasks, start_method, pool_size):
    multiprocessing.set_start_method(start_method, force=True)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size)
    tasks = [pool.apply_async(create_shm) for _ in range(tasks)]

    for task in tasks:
        name = task.get()
        print('Getting {}'.format(name))
        shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=name, create=False)
        shm.close()
        shm.unlink()
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--start_method', '-s',
        help='The multiproccessing start method to use. Default: %(default)s',
        default=multiprocessing.get_start_method(),
        choices=multiprocessing.get_all_start_methods()
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--pool_size', '-p',
        help='The number of processes in the pool. Default: %(default)s',
        type=int,
        default=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--tasks', '-t',
        help='Number of shared memory objects to create. Default: %(default)s',
        default=200,
        type=int
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.tasks, args.start_method, args.pool_size)
```

Given that `fork` is the only method that ends up displaying the warnings (for me, at least), maybe there is actually something to the following statement about it:

> The parent process uses os.fork() to fork the Python interpreter. The
> child process, when it begins, is effectively identical to the parent
> process. All resources of the parent are inherited by the child
> process. Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is
> problematic.

It's not surprising that the warnings from child processes persist/propagate if *all resources of the parent are inherited by the child processes*.

If you're feeling particularly adventurous, you can edit the [multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py) and update `warnings.warn` lines by adding `os.getpid()` to the printed strings. For instance, changing any warning with `"resource_tracker:"` to `"resource_tracker %d: " % (os.getpid())` should be sufficient. If you've done this, you will notice that the warnings come from various processes that are neither the child processes, nor the main process itself.

With those changes made, the following should help with double checking that the complaining resource trackers are as many as your `Pool` size, and their process IDs are different from the main process or the child processes:

```
chmod +x shm_test_script.py
./shm_test_script.py -p 10 -t 50 -s fork > log 2> err
awk -F ':' 'length($4) > 1 { print $4 }' err | sort | uniq -c
```

That should display ten lines, each of which prepended with the number of complaints from the corresponding resource tracker. Every line should also contain a PID that should be different from the main and child processes.

To recap, each child process should have its own resource tracker if it receives any work. Since you're not explicitly unlinking the shared memory objects in the child processes, the resources will likely get cleaned up when the child processes are destroyed.

I hope this helps answer some, if not all, of your questions.

Comment: I confirm that I only get the warnings when using the 'fork' start method.

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar in my work.
I have several micro service running each in a different console and therefore in a different process.

To get rid of the warning I register the shared memory name when creating it in each of the micro service.

Then when closing the micro service

```
    for shared_name in self.shared_memory_list_toclean:
        sm_temp = sm.SharedMemory(name=shared_name)
        sm_temp.close()
        sm_temp.unlink()
```

As each process is responsible for the unlinking of the shared memory.

Edit:
In fact I still have the issue with the warning when a process use a shared memory (enven if not creating it).
I solved it using the solution proposed by Diego Flores in https://bugs.python.org/issue39959

What I have done is to copy the file shared_memory.py from multiprocessing in my repo. and had the solution proposed :

Replacing

```
        from .resource_tracker import register
        register(self._name, "shared_memory")
```

on line 119 by

```
           if create:
            from multiprocessing.resource_tracker import register
            register(self._name, "shared_memory")
```

Then in my code using shared memories, instead of importing:

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory as sm
```

I will do:

```
import my_sharedmemory as sm
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you didnt modify the unregister command ? According to the PR it should be line 240.

Comment: You can also use the monkey-patched version of code based on https://bugs.python.org/file49859/mprt_monkeypatch.py
         https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/15989